# IDL and image format

Tags: idl

I'm starting to use IDL because I want to use some analysis tools for videos that I have found on internet ([https://physics.nyu.edu/~fcc4/HVM_site/HVM/software.html](https://physics.nyu.edu/%7Efcc4/HVM_site/HVM/software.html)), I already have installed IDL package and works properly... When I load my image in PNG format I got

```
IDL> a=read_image('Imag1.png')
IDL> help, a
A       BYTE       =Array[3,424,382]
```

The point is that the routine that I want to use need two dimensional float array that came from an image save as two dimensional byte array. Why is this a three dimensional array? Is it due to the RGB that png format use? Can I converge it to a two dimensional and don't lost the information? The tutorial use uncompressed tif, is the some free tool like VirtualDub which split videos with this format?

This is the image that I load in the code above

[image]